# Android httpresponse (urlencoded string) get attribute

Tags: android, httpresponse

Working with an OAuth API I need to retrieve the access_token attribute. Send the login information works fine and I do get a proper response back. The response is formatted as such:

```
access_token=SOMETOKEN&login=SOMELOGIN&apiKey=SOMEAPIKEY
```

Currently I'm getting the response as such:

```
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String content = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

Where the second line gets the String of the content as described. So what's coming back is an URL Encoded string, and I need to get the access_token value of that. However I'm not sure how to do this, I can't seem to find a method or anything for doing this, Would I have to parse it or is there some other methods to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found a solution to this located in the Twitter Api Me (http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home) StringUtil class, I'm not gonna paste it here, but its open sorce so if anyone needs it, go get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [URLDecoder.decode(content)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)

If that's the only problem, that should work.

Edit: I guess you already know this and you are looking for something more automatic, but just in case. I havent tested it.

```
String[] splitted = content.split("&");

//detect token
String token;
for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
if(splitted[i].startsWith("token"){
 String[] tokenSplitted = splitted[i].split("=");
token = tokenSplitted[1];
}
}
```

Comment: No I dont need to decode it, I need to get a specific argument of the String that could look like: access_token=n6hfcq3iio&login=username&apiKey=duksqmo98f So what I need to extract is n6hfcq3iio